# Creating an 'uneven' distance matrix using a data.frame of distances in r

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, distance

I have a data.frame of distances that I would like to use to create a heat map. To do so I must first create a distance object from the data.frame. My data.frame is 'uneven' i.e. I am comparing 2 species at one site to 3 species at another site:

```
 df<-data.frame("Sp1"=rep(c("a","b","c"),2),"Sp2"=c(rep("d",3),rep("e",3)),"Dist"=1:6)

  Sp1 Sp2 Dist
1   a   d    1
2   b   d    2
3   c   d    3
4   a   e    4
5   b   e    5
6   c   e    6
```

I have tried adapting a previous answer but it doesn't seem to work my distance matrix will be uneven i.e. a 3x2 matrix

```
 dij2 <- with(df, Dist)

 names <- with(df, unique(c(as.character("Sp1"), as.character("Sp2"))))

 dij3 <- with(df, structure(Dist,
                        Size = length(names),
                        Labels = names,
                        Diag = FALSE,
                        Upper = TRUE,
                       method = "user",
                        class = "dist"))
```

Thanks for any advice you may have on this matter

Comment: A distance matrix is constructed from a data frame or matrix that includes columns (representing species) and rows (representing sample sites) or the other way around. The distance measure is computed between rows so there are nrows(nrows-1)/2 distinct distances. If you have three species and two sites, you have one distance (between the sites) or 3 distances (between species). What you describe is not "uneven" - Three species by two sites will produce a symmetric matrix of 3 x 3 species for distances between species or 2 x 2 sites for distances between sites.

Comment: A distance matrix can also be calculated between species in term of their traits which is what I have done here. So the matrix shows the distance between species in terms of their trait similarity. I want to show the distance 1-6 in a heat map but need to convert my data frame to a distance object so that heat map tools in r can handle it.